# How to check if a checkbox created from an array is set to TRUE

Tags: javascript

I am starting to learn a bit of JavaScript. I am trying to create, let's say, some sort of a little game.

I have a matrix `n * n matrix` which consists of CHECKBOXES. If a certain set of CHECKBOXES is set to **TRUE**, output **whatever** (not strongly defined).

My issue is that when I set which checkboxes will be set to true, nothing happens.

Here is part of the code where I create a "starting point" for the matrix:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < matrix * matrix; i++)
{
    values[i] = "values" + i;
}
```

Now here is the part where I give the checkbox type to every single element in that array:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < matrix * matrix; i++)
{
    var checkbox = "<input type = 'checkbox' value = '" + values[i].checked + "' />";
    document.write(checkbox + values[i]);

    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
```

I know this won't work for matrices bigger than 2, but I wanna get a feel for smaller inputs first and work my way up.

Finally, this is part of the code where I check if certain boxes are set to true:

```js
if (values[1] == true && values[3] == true)
{
    document.write("You got it!"); // This doesn't get outputted :(
}
```

**Here is the full code:** https://pastebin.com/30Neb3zJ

I am really new to JS and any type of feedback/info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- All of the values in the `values` matrix look like strings, e.g. `values0`, `values1`, etc. When you test `if (values[1] == true && values[3] == true)`, you are testing whether a string value (e.g. `values1`) is equal to the Boolean value `true`.
- You're testing the values of an array which never change. I think you want to test the contents of the actual checkboxes. To do that you'll need to retrieve those DOM elements and test whether their [`.checked`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) property is `true`:
- You're testing the values immediately when the page loads, rather than after the user checks some checkboxes. You'll need to call `getAnswer()` after the user checks some boxes, or possibly every time they check a box.

So to test the checkboxes, and do it after the user has finished checking, you need to add an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) to all of the checkboxes (or to a "submit" button of some sort, depending on what you want to trigger the test).

Comment: I created a button which is accessing the getAnswer() function. Why value[i].checked == true wouldn't work?

Comment: Please update your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see your code. You can also post a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) but please don't put code in Pastebin.